# How do I specify which version of Java to use at terminal?

Tags: java, java-7, centos7

A CentOS 7 devbox has Java 8 installed.  I need to use Java 7 to compile jars.  So I downloaded and installed Java 7, but `java -version` still shows Java 8.  **How can I make sure that Java 7 is used to compile a jar at the command line?**

Here are the steps I took to install Java 7:

```
# wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u75-b13/jdk-7u75-linux-x64.rpm  
# rpm -ivh jdk-7u75-linux-x64.rpm
# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
# java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

As you can see, `java -version` still points to Java 8, even though `/usr/java/latest` points to the Java 7 version that was just downloaded and installed.

The command I want to run is `java -jar gs-actuator-service-0.1.0.jar`.  **Can someone show how to change the syntax in that specific command to specify the Java 7 version?  Or do I need to remove Java 8?  If so, what specific steps do I take?**

Comment: @JasonZ CentOS 7.  See OP.

Comment: just put the full path to your other java compiler

Comment: This question is not a duplicate indeed. Is there a way to open this question for answers again?

Answer (score 8):

If your goal is to change to that specific Java version as a one-time thing for the current session, then you can add the following to your list of commands.

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

If your goal is to do a more permanent switch to a specific version, then you can use the [`alternatives`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives) command to switch to Java 7 as the default.

```
alternatives --config java
```

Comment: The first command is what I need to change the JDK version by each terminal/session. Of course JAVA_HOME must be changed first. Huge thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -version
```

There is nothing magic about the JAVA_HOME environment variable.  It is simply a common convention for use in shell scripts that launch java apps.  A defined variable does nothing if it is not used.

Answer (score 0):

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/bin/java 1
alternatives --config java
```

Reference: [Centos forum](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5267)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10709223)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk The answer *does* include the essential part already, it includes the command to run to set which Java is in use.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk It does include the command. And the reference is for extra reading.

Comment: I found it helpful for my problem.. if you could add a little more discription on wht this command is useful and all, it will be really helpful.